# Last 30 days option is missing in Achievements

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, top-bar, achievements-dialog

Today I'm unable to see **`Last 30 days`** options in Achievements dropdown.

[image]

This might not be a bug maybe by design.  But I would like to know why it is not showing up and in what basis it is shown?

Comment: Thats odd, I can see my last 30 days; http://imgur.com/ixNu8Hi

Comment: Same, no repro here.

Comment: Repro. I can't see it too

Comment: @Stijn: I don't know about OP but I had achievements in the last 30 days

Comment: @Stijn Actually I can't understand.  How it is calculated?  I have mentioned in my question.  If I know that I would added the tag `bug`?

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan My no repo is Firefox 25.0.1 on windows 7. I'm afraid I don't have chrome

Comment: No repro in Chrome (31.0.1650.57) on Windows 7.

Comment: @RichardTingle Might be due to OS? Not sure, just to add it. I'm using Windows 8 and tested in latest version of IE, FF and chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We load the last `n` items, for very active users it will go back less time.  This is intentional - it's meant to show something for both the very active user as well as the user who only gets reputation a few times per month.

Very active users see their rep very often.  Given that the dropdown's purpose is being a summary, we're okay with it not going back that far...that's actually what's intended.