# Achievements header is overflown

Tags: bug, firefox, top-bar, achievements-dialog

While trying to take screenshot for this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209384/233367) Achievements header is little overflow outside **only in FF** and working perfectly in IE10 and latest chrome browser.
Managed to take 2 SS,

[image]
[image]

One more person @Richard Tingle is also having this problem, check his screenshot in this [**comments**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209384/last-30-days-option-is-missing-in-achievements#comment669967_209384)

Comment: Already reported here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta/207473#207473